# random.choice from list doesn't update

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to randomly select the image to load for the Angryball objects that spawn on the screen, but with my code, the program loads a random image and sticks to it for the entire duration of the main loop, so basically every object that i spawn has the same image. Is it a mistake in the update definition of the class or am i missing something in the main loop?

**Class**:

```
mob_images = [pygame.image.load("image1.png").convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load("image2.png").convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load("image3.png").convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load("image4.png").convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load("image5.png").convert_alpha()]
mob_image = random.choice(mob_images)

class Angryball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, pos_x, pos_y):
        super(Angryball, self).__init__()
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = pos_x
        self.rect.y = pos_y
        self.facing = 'LEFT'

    def update(self, screen):
        if self.rect.x <= 0:
            self.rect.right = screen.get_rect().width
            self.rect.top = random.randint(0, screen.get_rect().height)
        else:
            self.rect.move_ip(-5, 0)
```

**Sprites:**

```
angryball = Angryball(mob_image, 700, random.randrange(400))
sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
sprites.add(angryball)
```

**In the main loop:**

```
    sprites.update(screen)
    sprites.draw(screen)
```

Comment: Your random choice is like the xkcd random function: https://xkcd.com/221/. You choose it once, but then re-use that choice, instead of making a new random choice every time.

Comment: You're only doing the random choice once, at the beginning of that file. So that will run once the file is imported. If you want to have a different image every time, you have to include this random choice in the main loop.

Comment: I'm still learning, how can i recall mob_image to update it every time the object angryball is added? Can i update it when i call sprites.add(angryball)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either set a new image everytime you reset the position of Angryball:

```
...
class Angryball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, mob_images, pos_x, pos_y):
        super(Angryball, self).__init__()
        self.mob_images = mob_images
        self.image = random.choice(self.mob_images)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=pos_x, y=pos_y)
        self.facing = 'LEFT'

    def update(self, screen):
        if self.rect.x <= 0:
            self.rect.right = screen.get_rect().width
            self.rect.top = random.randint(0, screen.get_rect().height)
            self.image = random.choice(self.mob_images)
            # we assume all images are the same size
            # if not, we should call 'self.rect = self.image.get_rect()' again
        else:
            self.rect.move_ip(-5, 0)
...
mob_images = [pygame.image.load("image1.png").convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load("image2.png").convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load("image3.png").convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load("image4.png").convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load("image5.png").convert_alpha()]
angryball = Angryball(mob_images , 700, random.randrange(400))
...
```

Another idea is to create a new `Angryball` instance, which is probably a better idea anyway. Something like this:

```
...
class Angryball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, mob_images, pos_x, pos_y):
        super(Angryball, self).__init__()
        self.mob_images = mob_images
        self.image = random.choice(self.mob_images)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=pos_x, y=pos_y)
        self.facing = 'LEFT'

    def update(self, screen):
        if self.rect.x <= 0:
            newBall = Angryball(self.mob_images, 0, 0)
            for g in self.groups():
                g.add(newBall)
            self.kill()
            newBall.rect.right = screen.get_rect().width
            newBall.rect.top = random.randint(0, screen.get_rect().height)
        else:
            self.rect.move_ip(-5, 0)
...
mob_images = [pygame.image.load("image1.png").convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load("image2.png").convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load("image3.png").convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load("image4.png").convert_alpha(),pygame.image.load("image5.png").convert_alpha()]
angryball = Angryball(mob_images , 700, random.randrange(400))
...
```

Comment: The first soultion you proposed worked as intended, thank you! @sloth

Comment: Creating an entire new instance seems like overkill for this. Imagine if there are 100+ Angryball objects coming into view at the same time. In one time step 100+ objects would have to be created and 100+ destroyed. Considering the 100 objects are already loaded into memory, just updating their texture would achieve the same effect for a fraction of the performance loss. Why do you think creating a new instance is better here exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
angryball = Angryball(mob_image, 700, random.randrange(400))
```

to

```
angryball = Angryball(random.choice(mob_images), 700, random.randrange(400))
```

You want to make the image choice happen at random upon object creation. If you choose a random image before you make the object (like you're doing now), it stores that random image as a global variable (if it's not inside a function or class like I'm assuming) and just uses that image whenever you call `mob_image` (i.e. when you make an instance of Angryball as you are). If you pass in `random.choice(mob_images)` as a variable, it forces Python to choose a random image *each time* you create an instance of Angryball, giving a different random image as opposed to the static one chosen once like you have in your current code.

Comment: Made the change to angryball as suggested but the image still doesn't update, i think i should update it in the main loop but i don't know how

Comment: Are you trying to make it so that every time the Angryball is updated, the image is changed to a random image? If so then add a line that says `self.image = random.choice(mob_images)` to the `update` method.